# Attempt to access R environment produces unexpected results

Tags: r, environment-variables

I have a bunch of data frames named Ldat.1, Ldat.2, etc., in my normal R environment that I can access interactively.

From the console, I can type:

```
> dim(Ldat.1)[1]
[1] 40
> dim(Ldat.2)[1]
[1] 39
```

So I can tell that the first has 40 rows and the second has 39 rows.

However, with dozens of data frames, I want to write a script to tell me how many rows are in each frame.

I tried the following:

```
print(dim(Ldat.1)[1])
print(dim(Ldat.2)[1])
for (i in 1:2){
  namex<-paste("Ldat.",i,sep="")
  size<-dim(.GlobalEnv$namex)
  print(size[1])
}
```

and the console showed:

```
> print(dim(Ldat.1)[1])
[1] 40
> print(dim(Ldat.2)[1])
[1] 39
> for (i in 1:2){
+   namex<-paste("Ldat.",i,sep="")
+   size<-dim(.GlobalEnv$namex)
+   print(size[1])
+ }
NULL
NULL
```

It's easy enough to construct the strings:

```
for (i in 1:2){
  namex<-paste("Ldat.",i,sep="")
  size<-dim(namex)
  print(namex)
}
```

produces:

```
> for (i in 1:2){
+   namex<-paste("Ldat.",i,sep="")
+   size<-dim(namex)
+   print(namex)
+ }
[1] "Ldat.1"
[1] "Ldat.2"
```

But despite trying various combinations of "as.data.frame" and "envir=" I can't seem to get R to interpret the string "Ldat.1" as meaning the name of an object accessible from the console.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
for (i in 1:2){
   namex<-paste("Ldat.",i,sep="")
   size<-dim(.GlobalEnv[[namex]])
   print(size[1])
               }
```

The problem has nothing to do with environments and everything to do with the fact that `$` does not evaluate its second argument (it's first argument being the token name that precedes it, `.GlobalEnv` in this case). There is no object in `.GlobalEnv` named "namex". On the other hand "[[" does an evaluation step, so the value of `namex` (which is "Ldat.1" during the first pass of the for-loop) will get substituted and lookup will succeed.

Comment: That's perfect.  Even though I try to practice my R skills, it's hard to improve without advice from an expert.  Thanks.

Comment: If you wanted to use `sapply` you might then try: `sapply( mget( ls(patt="Ldat.") ), NROW)`, which would also find `Ldat.3` or `Ldat.x`

Answer (score 4):

**1)** This will list the names of each data frame and the number of rows it has:

```
sapply(Filter(is.data.frame, mget(ls())), nrow)
```

If we already had `nms`, a vector of names of data frames, then we could reduce this to:

```
nms <- c("Ldat.1", "Ldat.2")
sapply(mget(nms), nrow)
```

**2)** Here is another way:

```
simplify2array(Filter(Negate(is.null), eapply(.GlobalEnv, nrow)))
```

**3)** Also try the `ll` function in the R.oo package.

Comment: `mget` is one of those functions in `R` that you can just spend hours banging your head about a problem until you finally figure out that its what you need

Comment: Those syntax elements are very interesting.  I will be sure to write some test scripts to make sure that I understand them.  Thank you - your information has broadened my R horizons quite a bit.